# Replace entire row containing NaN in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a pandas dataframe in python that has NaN values.  If a row has an NaN value then I want to replace the entire row with the preceding row.

So this

```
    stock     label     open     high      low    close
0     CAT  09:31 AM  137.090  137.175  137.090  137.175
1     CAT  09:32 AM      NaN   -1.000   -1.000      NaN
```

Would become this

```
    stock     label     open     high      low    close
0     CAT  09:31 AM  137.090  137.175  137.090  137.175
1     CAT  09:32 AM  137.090  137.175  137.090  137.175
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `mask` and `isnull` to mask all row as NaN then we using `ffill`

```
df=df.set_index(['stock','label'])

df=df.mask(df.isnull().any(1)).ffill().reset_index()
df
Out[889]: 
  stock    label    open     high     low    close
0   CAT  09:31AM  137.09  137.175  137.09  137.175
1   CAT  09:32AM  137.09  137.175  137.09  137.175
```

Comment: awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: @pmillerhk YW : -) would you like accept and up-vote for this ?